# Google app script How to get fields in pre-filled link mode in google form

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to give a form link to someone which have already filled fields or have a default selected choices. 
what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do by using query string with google script and get the entry id to give a value.

the best practice "and the easiest way" 
go to the form edit page ..click responses tab and choose Get pre-filled URL. submit an option and you will be redirected to a page with the value link.